# Where can I find non-emoji icons for experiences and emotions?

Tags: icon, information-graphics, information-design

To help people make sense of the world, we need to make information crystal clear. Well-placed icons can reinforce meaning and draw the eye quickly to the relevant section on a page. I need to communicate experiences and emotions. Here are some examples:

Emotions

- Need
- Curiosity
- Desire to change the world
- Gratitude
- Motivation
- Personal satisfaction

Experiences

- Public recognition/accolade
- Interviewing someone
- Being under-resourced
- Helping people
- Drawing
- Taking a photograph
- Empathizing/listening

These are difficult concepts to illustrate, and emojis have done the job remarkably well. However, for my business audience, this not the direction I want to go. Ideally, I'd like to find a beautiful library of flat, similar-style icons that are all free. Realistically, though... Let's just say I'm open to whatever the community has to offer.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. This appears to be resource gathering.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for your attention. So I can learn how to better participate in this community, could you help me understand how it is too broad? It seems narrower in scope than "Where to find high-quality icon sets?", which is cited above as asking the same question.

Comment: @Scott One more question: Is resource gathering taboo here?  Or perhaps I should go about it differently? I fully acknowledge that resource gathering was my intention with this question. If that goes against the purpose of this site, I'll remove my question.

Comment: The site has grown a bit since 2012 (when that icon question was posed). So things have changed a bit and what is or is not acceptable has become slightly more stringent in the face of a non-beta, non-struggling community. While design problems are encouraged, open-ended "what's your opinion" type of questions aren't received well and do not work well with the StackExchange site model. To this end, general resource gathering questions are often pointed to older, existing questions. As in this case.

Comment: An example of a design problem rather than resource gathering would be along the lines of "I'm seeking to create emoji icons for 'Need', 'Curiousity, etc. -- I have this set of icons [insert images] however I feel these lack in XXXXX. How could I increase XXXX in this icon set?" This present a *direct* design issue and allows for objective, fact-based answers as opposed to answers such as "I think these icons work well."

Comment: Essentially, showing effort then asking how to solve an issue with *that effort* is much better than asking users to go find something for you.

Comment: @Scott thanks for taking time to teach me how to better participate on this site. I don't have a specific design question. What's the best next step for this question? I'm happy to delete it if that's the most beneficial thing to the community.